# Force Microsoft Visual Studio to show results only in output window (not in MS-DOS window) when using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I run my python code in `Microsoft Visual Studio 2013` it will open results in an environment like this:

[image]

How can I show results only in output window without changing to this environment (`MS-DOS`) as we have here:

[image]

Comment: The Visual Studio output window is meant for *Debug* output, not normal program output. As handy as it might be to have it for normal output, that's not what it's designed for. Other languages don't do this either.